# Hierarchical Clustering related

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I have a question concerning hierarchical clustering using R Language. I am trying to find out what values does the argument dist.metric takes of the function `hclust`. I wonder whether this is the same as in Python’s “metric”, but apparently I tried to use “cosine” there and the result was an error. So what values does this argument accept? If possible with an example provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different metrics in the `hclust` function:

> the agglomeration method to be used. This should be (an unambiguous
> abbreviation of) one of "ward.D", "ward.D2", "single", "complete",
> "average" (= UPGMA), "mcquitty" (= WPGMA), "median" (= WPGMC) or
> "centroid" (= UPGMC).

This means you can use for example `average`. Here is an example:

```
data <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=3)
d_m = dist(data, method="maximum")
hclust(d_m, method="average")

Call:
hclust(d = d_m, method = "average")

Cluster method   : average 
Distance         : maximum 
Number of objects: 3
```

As you can see the `cosine` is not available.

When using `dist.metric` in `hclust`:

```
hclust(d_m, method="average", dist.metric = "cosine")    
Error in hclust(d_m, method = "average", dist.metric = "cosine") : 
  unused argument (dist.metric = "cosine")
```

So there is no argument called `dist.metric`.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer and I will keep that in the back of my mind though I am more interested in the argument “dist.metric” and not “method”. If look at help of hclust you will see it in the end of the suggested arguments but I have not seen anyone use it, so I wondered about it.

Comment: dist argument in `hclust`?

Comment: @TheKrab, check my updated post.

Comment: Yes indeed, I was confused! Thank you for your immediate answer. I will proceed by creating a matrix with cosine distances and then use hierarchical clustering to that. thank you once again!